# Async function and callbacks inside a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

Inside this function:

```
function Example(array, callback){
    var toReturn = [];

    // variable 'array' has 2 elements in this case
    array.forEach(function(el){
        MongooseModel.AsyncFunction(el, function(err, doc){
            if(err || !doc){ return callback('Error'); }
            toReturn.push(doc)
        });
    });

    return callback(null, toReturn)
}
```

A few things to note:

1. `toReturn.push(doc)` doesn't work and on the last callback an empty
   array is returned. Why is that?
2. If there's an error, or !docs is true, `return callback('Error')` is never called. `return callback(null, toReturn)` is always called.

Also, if I put a callback above the async function, like this:

```
function Example(array, callback){
    var toReturn = [];

    // variable 'array' has 2 elements in this case
    array.forEach(function(el){
        // another callback here
        return callback('Error')
        MongooseModel.AsyncFunction(el, function(err, doc){
            if(err || !doc){ return callback('Error'); }
            toReturn.push(doc)
        });
    });

    return callback(null, toReturn)
}
```

the script crashes because multiple callbacks have been called. Why is forEach doing that and how to avoid it?

Comment: *"toReturn.push(doc) doesn't work and on the last callback an empty array is returned. Why is that?"* It does work. But `callback(null, toReturn)` is executed before `toReturn.push(doc)` ever had a chance to be executed. It seems like you should already know why: Because the code you execute inside the `forEach` callback is *asynchronous*.  Have a look at [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/218196) to learn more.

Comment: One of these might help: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnode.js%5D+async+function+forEach .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Your questions

> toReturn.push(doc) doesn't work and on the last callback an empty array is returned. Why is that?

You're calling `callback` before `MongooseModel.AsyncFunction` gets any chance to execute your `function(err,doc)`.

> If there's an error, or !docs is true, return callback('Error') is never called. return callback(null, toReturn) is always called.

The successful return is called immediately after scheduling your async functions. It's still possible that the `callback('Error')` will be called sometime later by `MongooseModel.AsyncFunction`.

> the script crashes because multiple callbacks have been called

That's exactly the behaviour you asked for! Your second code literally says: "For each element, call the callback once".

---

### Some pointers

All in all, I think the single thing you have wrong is that calling the callback somewhat resembles returning from the function.

That's not the case! Your function `Example` is supposed to schedule some async things to happen, then return immediately (returning nothing) but promising that either `callback(error)` or `callback(null, success)` will be called **sometime later in the future**.

Therefore, it doesn't make sense to ever say `return callback()` - just `callback()` will do. By the time that you have some data to call `callback` with, the function `Example` will already have finished executing. The function that eventually calls `callback` will the an anonymous function passed to `MongooseModel.AsyncFunction`, not `Example` itself.

---

### Now what?

You could try an approach like this:

```
function Example(array, callback){
    var toReturn = [];
    var previousError = false;

    array.forEach(function(el){
        MongooseModel.AsyncFunction(el, function(err, doc){
            if (previousError) {
                return;
            }
            if(err || !doc) {
                previousError = true;
                callback('Error');
            }
            toReturn.push(doc)
            if (toReturn.length === array.length) {
                // that was the last push - we have completed
                callback(null, toReturn);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Stuff that happens here:

- Every time your `AsyncFunction` completes, you aggregate the result. If that was the last one, you can finally call `callback` and pass the whole data. (Otherwise, we're waiting for a few more functions, so no `callback`)
- If there was an error somewhere along the way, we report it immediately, but also take a note that the error has been reported already, so that further executions of `AsyncFunction` that have been scheduled don't do anything in particular. This prevents your `callback` from potentially being called twice or more.
- Be careful though - the order of elements inside `toReturn` will be random, depending on which async tasks complete first.

---

### But this is messy

Oh yes. That's why we don't really do callbacks anymore. There's a pattern called [`promises`](https://www.promisejs.org/) that makes it significantly easier to work with async callback spaghetti, I suggest to read up a little on this topic before moving forward.

- https://www.promisejs.org/

### Let's make it neat

Using promises, this kind of code would look something like:

```
function Example(array) {
    var promises = array.map(function(el) {
        return MongooseModel.AsyncFunction(el);
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

which is much shorter and also doesn't have any problems with error handling or ordering of output items like our previous example.

Usage is simple - instead of this

```
Example([1, 2, 3], function(error, results) {
    if (error !== null) {
        // ...
    } else { 
        // ...
    }
})
```

you call like this:

```
Example([1, 2, 3]).then(
    function(results) {
        // ...
    },
    function(error) {
        // ...
    }
);
```

Oh, this relies on `MongooseModel.AsyncFunction` returning a promise on itself, but [Mongoose already does this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) and so do most libraries. If a library doesn't, you can easily add the promise support (see [NodeRedis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#promises) for example).

**How to do something with each result of `AsyncFunction` before returning it?**

Easy too!

```
function Example(array) {
    var promises = array.map(function(el) {
        return MongooseModel.AsyncFunction(el).then(function(doc) {
            return doc + "some modifications";
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Or if you need additional error handling:

```
function Example(array) {
    var promises = array.map(function(el) {
        return MongooseModel.AsyncFunction(el).then(function(doc) {
            if (theresSomethingWrongWith(doc) {
                return Promise.reject(new Error("ouch!"));
            }
            return doc + "some modifications";
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Think of returning a rejected promise as something similar to raising an exception - it will naturally bubble up all the way to the returning promise of `Example`.

Comment: Great answer! Just one thing. You said it doesn't make sense to ever say return callback(), but I find that if I say just callback(), the execution  flow of the function continues, and another callback() can be called, while return callback() stops the execution flow. It's just that it doesn't work that way inside a forEach

Comment: Yeah, this one of the problems with callbacks. Promises are neater - you actually return them. But the best return of investment is when it comes to error handling and things like `Promise.all`.

Comment: Expanded with an example with promises

Answer (score 2):

Basically, your function executes in the following order:

1. Trigger the async action for each element in `array`
2. Return immediately after all the async calls were triggered
3. Async calls return with results, but your function returned already - so they are ending up nowhere.

In order to perform multiple async calls and return their results, you need to wait for all of them to finish. I usually solve this problem with the help of the library [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/), which even gives you control over how the async calls should be executed (in series or in parallel). For example, you can call [async.parallel](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel) with an array of async functions:

```
async.parallel(array.map(function() {
  return MongooseModel.AsyncFunction(...)
}), function(err, results) {
  // all the async calls are finished, do something with the results
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use promises because you need to wait when all async calls will be done before returning result. Here is example:

```
function Example(array, callback){
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var toReturn = [];

        array.forEach(function(el){
            MongooseModel.AsyncFunction(el, function(err, doc){
                if(err || !doc) {
                    return reject();
                }
                toReturn.push(doc);
                if (toReturn.length === array.length) {
                    resolve(toReturn);
                }
            });
        });
    })
        .then(callback)
        .catch(function() {
            callback('error');
        });
}
```

And here you can read more about promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Wouldn't that always reject the promise? Also, I think one would return the promise instead of making the function accept a callback (but that depends on the OP's circumstances of course).

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. Updated comment

Comment: Brr, you provided an example with promises and that's cool but you didn't really use anything like `Promise.all()` which would REALLY simplify this kind of code and show off why promises are useful in the first place